# Item opening with previous item Id from SharePoint list view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, list-form

We have an application in SharePoint Online that creates a user custom action at web level to add a button to list ribbon. This button navigates to an .aspx page that application puts in a library in the site. Details of user custom action are given at the bottom.

This has been working all fine for several years. In last few days, we see a strange issue. When opening items from any list in the site (SP classic UI list view), the form that opens is that of previously clicked item. So when user clicks first time in list to open item, say item with Id 2, it opens that item. After that when user closes this item and clicks on item with Id 3, it will open the item with Id 2. Next, when user clicks on item with say Id 5, it will open the item with Id 3. And so on, the item opens with Id that was opened earlier.

When we remove the user custom action from list ribbon, problem goes away and items open with correct item Id. This is happening only in Chrome browser and sometimes in Edge also. Problem is not there in other browsers. Any ideas on what could be causing this and how to fix.

Environment: SharePoint Online Classic UI only (not in Modern UI)

User custom action markup:

```
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
    <d:ClientSideComponentId m:type="Edm.Guid">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d:ClientSideComponentId>
    <d:ClientSideComponentProperties/>
    <d:CommandUIExtension>
        <CommandUIExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
            <CommandUIDefinitions>
                <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.List.Settings.Controls._children">
                    <Button Id="30f6967538914455a13febd3eadb2cc2" CommandType="General" Image16by16="https://--host--/default16x16.png" Image32by32="https://--host--/default32x32.png" ToolTipTitle="Column Formatting" ToolTipDescription="Click to Configure Formatting" LabelText="Column Formatting" Sequence="1" TemplateAlias="o1" Command="30f6967538914455a13febd3eadb2cc2CMDCommand"/>
                </CommandUIDefinition>
                <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Library.Settings.Controls._children">
                    <Button Id="0e2cbe2d7ad64bdd9d0ed7362661667c" CommandType="General" Image16by16="https://--host--/default16x16.png" Image32by32="https://--host--/default32x32.png" ToolTipTitle="Column Formatting" ToolTipDescription="Click to Configure Column Column Formatting" LabelText="Column Formatting" Sequence="1" TemplateAlias="o1" Command="0e2cbe2d7ad64bdd9d0ed7362661667cCMDCommand"/>
                </CommandUIDefinition>
            </CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIHandlers>
                <CommandUIHandler Command="30f6967538914455a13febd3eadb2cc2CMDCommand" CommandAction="~Site/AppsLib/ColumnFormat/Pages/FormatColumnSettings.aspx?ListID={ListId}&amp;Source={Source}"/>
                <CommandUIHandler Command="0e2cbe2d7ad64bdd9d0ed7362661667cCMDCommand" CommandAction="~Site/AppsLib/ColumnFormat/Pages/FormatColumnSettings.aspx?ListID={ListId}&amp;Source={Source}"/>
            </CommandUIHandlers>
        </CommandUIExtension>
    </d:CommandUIExtension>
    <d:Description m:null="true"/>
    <d:Group m:null="true"/>
    <d:HostProperties/>
    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid">413e3e67-9785-4512-9418-366932acc127</d:Id>
    <d:ImageUrl m:null="true"/>
    <d:Location>CommandUI.Ribbon</d:Location>
    <d:Name>ColumnFormatSettings</d:Name>
    <d:RegistrationId>0x01</d:RegistrationId>
    <d:RegistrationType m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:RegistrationType>
    <d:Rights m:type="SP.BasePermissions">
        <d:High m:type="Edm.Int64">0</d:High>
        <d:Low m:type="Edm.Int64">0</d:Low>
    </d:Rights>
    <d:Scope m:type="Edm.Int32">3</d:Scope>
    <d:ScriptBlock m:null="true"/>
    <d:ScriptSrc m:null="true"/>
    <d:Sequence m:type="Edm.Int32">1002</d:Sequence>
    <d:Title>ColumnFormatSettings</d:Title>
    <d:Url m:null="true"/>
    <d:VersionOfUserCustomAction>16.0.1.0</d:VersionOfUserCustomAction>
</m:properties>
```